# Add image behind CSS mask

Tags: html, css

How do can I get the background image look like it's being shown on the phone? So I have the iPhone masked and I want to put an image on the screen of the phone. How do I do this? I tried playing with z-index but it doesn't work. Here's what I'm trying to achieve [image]

```css
div{
  width: 302px;
  height: 605px;
  background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xs/d/images/overview/hardware_display_iphonexsmax_gold_portrait_large_2x.jpg);
  background-size: 302px 605px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 302px 605px;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xs/d/images/overview/hardware_display_iphonexsmax_gold_portrait_mask_large.svg);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.background{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 265px;
  height: 571px;
  background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xr/d/images/overview/screen_display_iphonexr_large_2x.jpg);
  background-size: 265px 571px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>

<div class="background"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you were having is that the `div` styles you applied to the phone were also being applied to the `.background`. By giving the phone it's own separate class you can style them individually.

I've updated your example below.

```css
    .phone {
  width: 302px;
  height: 605px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xs/d/images/overview/hardware_display_iphonexsmax_gold_portrait_large_2x.jpg);
  background-size: 302px 605px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 302px 605px;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xs/d/images/overview/hardware_display_iphonexsmax_gold_portrait_mask_large.svg);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 280px;
  height: 580px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/v/iphone-xr/d/images/overview/screen_display_iphonexr_large_2x.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="phone"></div>

<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to get sleep, my brain clearly isn't working.